# How to solve a problem with ArrayLists recursively

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to write a program that "solves a circle".  The Circle class contains an ArrayList of Triangle Objects and an ArrayList of Integers.  The Triangle objects each have three int instance fields that represent three numbers at the vertices of each triangle.  There is also a Pairs class (you can see all of the code I have in the "code" section)
Here is an example of the setup using four triangles that is not solved:

[image: Unsolved circle]

And here is the same circle after it has been "solved":

[image: Solved circle]

The Circle in the second picture is a solved Circle because the number on any arc of the circle is equal to the sum of the two vertex numbers next to it:  6 = 1+5, 15 = 6+9, 11 = 7+4, and 9 = 5+4.  Note that this was obtained by rotating the given triangles.  This is analagous in the code to simply changing the Pair that is present in the solution for each triangle (where a "Pair" is an object of two ints, where those ints are the values on the circle for each triangle)

A Circle isn't always given in a "solved" state.  If this is the case, the triangles can be rotated so that the circle will be in the solved state.  The precondition of any given circle is that there is a solved state, so the numbers will always line up.

A circle will always have at least two triangles and there is no (practical) maximum number.  Every given circle will always be solvable, meaning there is a way to rotate each triangle so that the number on the circle is the result of the sum of the two adjacent vertices from the two different triangles.

The point of the program is not to alter any of the given instance fields; instead, I just want to create a method called solveCircle that returns an ArrayList of Pairs that represents the solution to the Circle.  In the above example, the solveCircle method would return an ArrayList containing the following pairs:  (4,1), (5,6), (9,7), (4,5). These pairs are in the solution because they are all pairs of numbers on a triangle, and each pair is also on the circle. Note that the solution goes counter-clockwise around the circle.

My gut is telling me that this process should involve some type of recursion, since a loop would be tricky due to the circular nature of the circle; in other words, I could loop through each pair of triangles finding the proper solution, but there could easily be more than one, and comparing each one with the solution to the next sum seems like it will be inefficient; recursion seems like a better option but I'm not sure what to apply the recursion to...what alrgorithm should I use and what is even the base case?

```
public class Triangle
{
    private int num1;
    private int num2;
    private int num3;

    public Triangle(int n1, int n2, int n3)
    {
        num1 = n1;
        num2 = n2;
        num3 = n3;
    }

    public ArrayList<Pair> getPairs()
    {
        ArrayList<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<Pair>();
        pairs.add(new Pair(num1, num2));
        pairs.add(new Pair(num2, num3));
        pairs.add(new Pair(num3, num1));
        return pairs;
    }
}
```

```
class Pair
{
    private int p1;
    private int p2;

    public Pair(int x, int y)
    {
        p1 = x;
        p2 = y;
    }
}
```

```
public class Circle
{
    private ArrayList<Triangle> triangles;
    private ArrayList<Integer> sums;

    public Wheel(ArrayList<Integer> s, ArrayList<Triangle> t)
    {
        triangles = t;
        sums = s;
    }

    public ArrayList<Pair> solveCircle()
    {
        //need help here
    }
}
```

Comment: "counterclockwise," but which comes first: triangle 0 or sum 0?

Comment: Triangle 0 would come first, so I would use triangle 0 and triangle 1 to find sum 1, and so on, until I get to Triangle "size()-1".  Then I would use that and Triangle 0 with sum 0.  The size of the sum ArrayList will be one less than the size of the Triangle ArrayList.

Comment: I would use the Sudoku approach. Go around the circle and find the triangle that has the minimum number of valid orientations. If there's only one valid orientation, choose that orientation, and lock the triangle. If there are two or three valid orientations, then choose one, and recurse.

Comment: I think my problem is that I'm confused about the concept of recursion when it isn't used in sequences of numbers or situations like a factorial or a sum.  In this case, I'm not really sure what the recursion is.  How would I write the base case?  I think I just need an example of how this is working like, for example, in the 4-triangle Circle that I gave as an example.

Comment: I would add a `state` variable to the `Triangle` class. There are two states: `Undecided` and `Locked`. At each level of recursion, one triangle is assigned an orientation, and locked. Which means that at each level of recursion there is one less undecided triangle. Successful base case: all of the triangles are locked. Otherwise, find an undecided triangle with the least number of valid orientations. Choose an orientation for that triangle, lock it, and recurse. Note that there may be an undecided triangle with no valid orientations. That's the failed base case.

Comment: you said " The size of the sum ArrayList will be one less than the size of the Triangle ArrayList. " how can that be? count the triangles and sums in the photo. they are the same count.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [tree](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/tree_data_structure.htm) to separate the triangles that are solved from the ones that are unsolved. The same for the circles that are solved and that are unsolved. This way, you would make it a `log n` search function that would ignore the solved ones, thus avoiding unnecessary comparisons.

```
if (solved)
    add to left side of the tree
else 
    add to right side of the tree
```

The complexity as well for this could be an extreme overkill depending on the use case.

Comment: I haven't learned about trees yet in my class and I can't use anything that hasn't been used.

I don't understand what you mean by "triangles that are solved".  I won't know if a triangle is correct unless the entire circle is solved correctly.  For example, if I have a sum of 10, and I have two adjacent triangles with vertices 3,4,8 and 7,6,2, there would be three different ways that they could be arranged that would be correct; but only one would work based on the other information in the circle, namely the other sums and other triangles.

Comment: Edit your question with a little more example on how one would receive the problem. For example, from this, I can't understand the maximum size of the circle, and what's the domain/range of the values existent for the problem.

Comment: This is why I think it has something to do with being recurvsive, where I would check if two triangles are correct, then if they are check if the third one works and, if it does move on to the fourth but if it doesn't, go back and revisit the first two triangles.  I'm just not certain how to implement that.

Comment: Edited with an example of a "given" Circle and then the solved version.  I need to write the code that will take that given Circle and then produce an ArrayList of Pairs that represent the pairs of vertices of each triangle that are part of the solution.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. A triangle is not "solved" in isolation. It may need to be rotated again depending on what comes later.

Comment: Previously, he mentioned that triangles could be solved and then would need to be checked with other triangles, I suppose this applies to circles, although I still think the question isn't quite clear on how it is applied.

Answer (score 0):

for the initial step, you call the helper three times: once for each pair, until a success is returned (boolean could be used to indicate success.)

the helper performs the recursive step.

for the recursive step, you have a sum extending behind you, an integer which you must combine with to meet that sum, and three possible ways to acheive it... however you do not return success unless your recursive call also returns success

for the terminal step, there is no rotating allowed, just a final true or false for did I complete the sum behind me.

Comment: So my helper function is a boolean function that returns true if the sum of the two vertices is equal to the sum I want?
I'm a little lost with your explanation (maybe because I'm having trouble picturing this as recursive in the same way that the fibonacci numbers are recursive).

I apologize for the lapse in time for responses; I was attempting to do this on my own without recursion.  I came up with something but it is messy and, unfortunately, it does not output the correct answer.

Comment: the helper function returns true IF its current rotation matches the required sum behind it AND the recursive call is also true ELSE it tries the next rotation UNTIL it has tried all three THEN it returns false